# JTable appearing blank

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I will only post the part that matters.

I have created a JFrame with a JPanel in it, that contains some JTextFields, JTextAreas and a JList. I know want to add a JTable to show some results, but it will appear blank. I tried checking out some posts, but I wasn't able to fix it.

I entered 2 rows manually, but they wouldn't appear. Nor would the column names. Please help!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI_Automata_Ex_1 extends JFrame {

    public static int ScreenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    public static int ScreenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

    public static int WindowWidth = ScreenWidth*3/4;
    public static int WindowHeight = WindowWidth*9/16;

    public static int unit = WindowWidth/160;

    // tables used
    static String[] columnNames = {"word", "length", "result"};
    static Object[][] data = {{"abbaa", new Integer (5), "belongs"}, {"baabbb", new Integer (6), "does not belong"}};
    public static JTable table_saved_words = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    public static DefaultTableModel dtm_saved_words = new DefaultTableModel();
    public static JScrollPane sp_saved_words;

    public GUI_Automata_Ex_1 () {

        // this will only run on ultrawide screens (e.g. 21:9 or 32:9) because the window is 16:9 optimized
        if (ScreenWidth/2 > ScreenHeight) {
            WindowHeight = ScreenHeight*3/4;
            WindowWidth = WindowHeight*16/9;
            unit = WindowWidth/160;
        }

        this.setTitle("Automata Theory 1st Excercise");
        this.setBounds(ScreenWidth/2-WindowWidth/2,ScreenHeight/2-WindowHeight/2,WindowWidth,WindowHeight);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(colorBG);

        Board board = new Board();
        this.setContentPane(board);
        this.setLayout(null);

        // TABLES

        // settings for table_saved_words
        table_saved_words.setBackground(Color.white);
        table_saved_words.setFont(fontM);
        table_saved_words.setModel(dtm_saved_words);
        table_saved_words.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(unit*86, unit*50));
        table_saved_words.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        sp_saved_words = new JScrollPane(table_saved_words);
        board.add(sp_saved_words);
        sp_saved_words.setBounds(unit*68, unit*32, unit*86, unit*50);
        sp_saved_words.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
        sp_saved_words.setViewportView(table_saved_words);
        sp_saved_words.setVisible(false);

        dtm_saved_words.addRow(new Object[]{"aabbbbaa", 5, "belongs"});

    }

    public class Board extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

        }
    }

}

}
```

Here is a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHtLf.png

The JTable is on the bottom-right. I did not include the code part for the other J-components.

What I want to do after I get the lists to show is simply add some rows as the window runs (words that the user enters and either belong to a dictionary or not and their length), but the part I'm stuck on is getting the JTable to show the columns and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table model has no columns, so it never shows the data you add to it.

From the [documentation for the zero-argument DefaultTableModel constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#%3Cinit%3E())

> Constructs a default `DefaultTableModel` which is a table of zero columns and zero rows.

Initially, your table has a valid table model created automatically:

```
JTable table_saved_words = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

But then you create a new model, with no columns:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm_saved_words = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!